# how to spring Jpa.unsafe to sort a json field in postgresql

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

In spring jpa doc, the example shows a way to sort by a sql function like Length(field).

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query("select u from User u where u.lastname like ?1%")
  List<User> findByAndSort(String lastname, Sort sort);

  @Query("select u.id, LENGTH(u.firstname) as fn_len from User u where u.lastname like ?1%")
  List<Object[]> findByAsArrayAndSort(String lastname, Sort sort);
}

repo.findByAndSort("targaryen", JpaSort.unsafe("LENGTH(firstname)"));
```

So I try to sort a json field in postgres, the code is like

```
@Query("select u from User u where u.loginName like ?1%")
List<User> findByAndSort(String loginName, Sort sort);

repo.findAllAndSort("jack", JpaSort.unsafe("extra ->> 'info'"));
```

extra is the name of the field in postgres and it is a jsonb type.

Unluckily, it returns error :

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: > near line 1, column 88 [select u from com.xx.user.model.User u where u.loginName like ?1 order by u.extra ->> 'info' asc]
```

it seems that error happens in process of hibernate.

following sql works, so I want to generate it through jpa.

```sql
SELECT * from tbl_user order by extra ->> 'info' desc;
```

Comment: What does `"extra ->> 'info'"` means?

Comment: that is how postgresql gets value with key from jsonb type. for example: "extra" is jsonb type and the value is {"info": "jsoncontext"}. "extra ->> 'info'" can return "jsoncontext".

Comment: Did you get any solution for this problem @Tttttsing

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasDilawar you can create a function used to extract value from json. and call the function instead of using ->>

Comment: @Tttttsing Would you mind sharing your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will put my solution here.

Hibernate just doesn't understand that the `->>` is json/jsonb operator.
We need to put the method name bound to the operator.
We could get it in PSQL by the request:

```
select * from pg_operator where oprname = '->>'
```

For my PSQL 9.4, it shows that the method name is the `json_array_element_text` in the `oprcode` column.

So I just can replace it with the following:

```
JpaSort.unsafe("json_array_element_text(extra, 'info')")
```

It does work for me.